# Probability of centimeter scale meteoroids killing astronauts

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, meteoroid

The maximum impact velocity for a meteoroid orbiting the Sun is 72km/s at 1AU. At this velocity, it has an energy density of 2,592 MJ/kg, or 620kgTNT/kg.

This means that a 10cm diameter sphere of ice has the energy of a car bomb. For an iron sphere, it goes up to a respectable truck bomb.

A more typical velocity is between 51 and 17km/s, at which the energy density is between 1301 and 145MJ/kg. This corresponds to between 311 and 35kgTNT/kg. Our 10cm meteoroid could still easily kill an astronaut.

It may be said that such a projectile is too small to be detected by radar commonly deployed in manned spacecraft. My question is what are the odds of a projectile too small to be detected blowing up a manned spacecraft or astronaut?

Comment: Hmm... to detect a 1 cm object at 30 km/s with current technology might give you order 1 millisecond warning, does that count as useful? As OrganicMarble points out, you might narrow down this question and ask additional questions after this receives an answer. For example, this question could be "What are the estimates for the size and speed distributions of meteoroids at the Moon big enough to do structural damage?" You could ask a separate question about detection technology for small, fast projectiles, though I wish we had a "Warfare Technology SE" to ask it in :-)

Comment: @uhoh okay, I will edit the question

Comment: "...radar commonly deployed in manned spacecraft..." No, it is not, at least for potential impact detection. That is all based on ground assets.

Comment: Well, are we sure mm scale meteorite are harmless at orbital speeds?

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer because size distribution of the impactors is not given and because it only addresses EVA**

> ...the probability of a fatality is about 1.4x10<sup>-3</sup> without shielding and 1.1x10<sup>-3</sup> per 624 hours of EVA with shielding...

Source: [Risks of particle hits during space walks in low Earth orbit](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/913673)

A different study gives the risk of Loss of EVA CrewMember (LECM) - defined as instant death during a six hour EVA on and around the Shuttle repairing the orbiter's heat shield.

[image]

Impact damage was the largest contributor to the risk at odds of 1:6,300 (1.6x10<sup>-4</sup>).

Source: [Extravehicular Activity
Probabilistic Risk
Assessment Overview for
Thermal Protection System
Repair on the Hubble Space
Telescope
Servicing Mission](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110015551/downloads/20110015551.pdf)

Again, impactor size distribution is not mentioned.

Comment: the parts about the moon have been edited out of the question, but I'm pretty sure that the LEO environment is more densely particled than the lunar surface and cislunar environment.  That could change if you were doing something like landing and launching Starships all the time

Comment: "per 624 hours" seems like an odd denominator to use, is it correct?

Comment: @RussellBorogove from the link:  "We computed the risk for a peak year of EVA activity, assumed by NASA to consist of 624 hours of EVA exposure."

Comment: NB - the Gruen model for meteoroid flux was the standard for a couple decades and is easy to understand (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0019103585901216, apologies if paywalled). The size distribution is a power law, and the EVA suits could be vulnerable to particles smaller than 1mm in size, of which there are hundreds of millions (of just orbital debris), let alone meteoroids.

Comment: @costrom thank you for the link.